# Comparing C macros

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I have addressing macros (it's on a microcontroller, so accessing physical address is OK) that break down to this (after a long sequence of conditional defines, attributes, etc):

```
#define ADDR_A (*18)
#define ADDR_B (*30)
#define ADDR_C (*18)
```

I would like to compare them so I can optimize the compilation:

```
#if ADDR_A==ADDR_C
    return 1;
#else
    return 0;
#endif
```

But I get "error: operator '*' has no left operand" which makes sense. Is it possible to compare the DEFINITIONS of macros. I have a hunch I could convert them to string somehow to compare, but I haven't found a way (like with the # for a macro argument).

And no, I'm not looking to do this at runtime as I'm counting the cycles.

Comment: That is not valid C. How is the compiler supposed to know it is an address and which type the object has? The rest of your question is not clear. What doy you want to compare and why? It smells like an XY-problem.

Comment: I fully agree with @Olaf. Additionally, all C compilers I've used optimize a normal `if` statement away, if the expression has only literal constants (as it would if you were to compare the addresses of two memory mapped registers); and, since you are on a microcontroller, you definitely should have optimizations enabled anyway. In other words, there is no need to rely on the *preprocessor* for optimizing the related code; any half-decent C compiler can and will do it for you (if you use a normal C `if` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare strings in an `#if`, because:

- you can only use `#if` with constant expressions
- strings can only be compared using a loop or a function
- loops aren't constant expressions
- and:

  > Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call,
  >   or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not
  >   evaluated. *(C11, 6.6P3)*

The best I can think of is to split up the addresses and the dereferencing into two different macros, like:

```
#define ADDR_A (18)
#define ADDR_B (30)
#define ADDR_C (18)
#define GET_A (*ADDR_A)
#define GET_B (*ADDR_B)
#define GET_C (*ADDR_C)

#if ADDR_A == ADDR_B
return 1
#else
return 0
#endif
```

Note that checking the equality of constants "at runtime" will be elided by pretty much any compiler worth its salt; in [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/2URAqH), the compiler just generates the equivalent of `return 1` because it knows at compile-time that the condition will evaluate to false; counting cycles is a red herring here, because these comparisons will be elided.

Also, for what it's worth, I'm not sure how you're using those macros (I can't construct an example in my head where they would be syntactically valid), but I have a feeling your code would be easier to understand if you just made your macros contain the addresses and you dereference those addresses inline in your code. Were I reading your code, I would much prefer:

```
#define ADDR_A (18)
#define ADDR_B (30)
#define ADDR_C (18)

if (ADDR_A == ADDR_B)
    return 1
return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting only the addresses in the macros, and the type information separately?

```
#define ADDR_A (18)
#define ADDR_B (30)
#define ADDR_C (18)

unsigned uint16_t *A = (uint16_t*)ADDR_A;
unsigned uint16_t *B = (uint16_t*)ADDR_B;
unsigned uint16_t *C = (uint16_t*)ADDR_C;
```

Then you can use your tests.

Alternatively, skip the preprocessor, and just do it in C:

```
unsigned uint16_t *const A = (uint16_t*)18;
unsigned uint16_t *const B = (uint16_t*)30;
unsigned uint16_t *const C = (uint16_t*)18;

int f()
{
    if (A == C)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Unless you have an *extremely* low-quality compiler, you can expect it to recognise `A==C` as a constant expression and simplify the code accordingly.